# PyQt5 Switch between window after time in a loop

Tags: python, pyqt

i use the code below, found on stackoverflow. i want to build a loop which getting started with a button on the main window. After clicked window2 should open for 30 seconds. then window3 should open for 30 seconds. then window2 should open and so on.

i make a slide methode but it wont work.

i try it with the window2() and window3() and slide() methode

what is my target?

i want a slideshow with the two window(window2 & window3) that alternate.
not more but it is an endless loop

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
                             QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLabel)

class Window2(QMainWindow):                           # <===
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window22222")

class Window3(QMainWindow):                           # <===
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window333333")

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "First Window"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500

        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton.move(275, 200)
        self.pushButton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.window2)      
        
        
        self.pushButton1 = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton1.move(20, 20)
        self.pushButton1.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.slide)           

        self.main_window()
        

    def main_window(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Manager", self)
        self.label.move(285, 175)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    
    
      def window2(self):                                             # <===
        self.w2 = Window2()
        self.w2.show()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.w3 = Window3()
        self.w3.show()
        self.w2.hide()
        self.window3()
        
        #self.hide()
    def window3(self):                                             # <===
        self.w3 = Window3()
        self.w3.show()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.w2 = Window2()
        self.w2.show()
        self.w3.hide()
        self.window2()
        
        #self.hide()

    def slide(self):
        print ("slide")
        self.window2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You left out `import time`, but otherwise this code works with delay of 5 seconds instead of 30. However, your app will be unresponsive if you use `time.sleep()`. You should investigate using [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QTimer) instead, specifically, the singleShot method.

Comment: Could you add some detail about the problem you're encountering? The question doesn't mention what isn't working for you.

Comment: my problem is that i will not open window2 or window3. i think it is an endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
#import time
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
                             QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLabel)

class Window2(QMainWindow):                          
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window 22222")

class Window3(QMainWindow):                           
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window 333333")

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "First Window"
        self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height = 100, 100, 680, 500
        
        self.flag = ...

        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton.move(275, 200)
        self.pushButton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.start_slide(True)) #(self.window2)      
        
        self.pushButton1 = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.pushButton1.move(20, 20)
        self.pushButton1.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.start_slide(False))   
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.main_window()
        
        self.w2 = Window2()
        self.w3 = Window3()
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.viewWindows)

    def start_slide(self, flag):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.w3.hide()
        self.w2.hide()
        if flag: self.w2.show()
        else: self.w3.show()
        self.flag = not flag
        self.timer.start(5000)

    def viewWindows(self):
        if self.flag:
            self.w2.show()
            self.w3.hide()
        else:
            self.w3.show()
            self.w2.hide()
        self.flag = not self.flag
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.w2.close()
        self.w3.close()
        self.close()
        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    def main_window(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Manager", self)
        self.label.move(285, 175)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]